# 'textAdjust' is not allowed to appear in element 'textField'

Tags: jasper-reports

```
<textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" isBlankWhenNull="true">    
    <reportElement> .... </reportElement>
    <box>.... </box>
    <textelement> ... </textElement>
</textfield>
```

I am getting error lineNumber: 97; columnNumber: 61; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'textAdjust' is not allowed to appear in element 'textField'.

If i remove the textAdjust field from the xml then it compiles good. Is it safer to remove the **textAdjust** field from the jrxml and what is the impact because of removing this. I am new to jasper reporting.

Comment: Maybe it's a version mismatch. textAdjust is kinda new attribute to replace stretchWithOverflow. Maybe you are trying to open a more recent report with an old version of studio. Or trying to deploy a new report to an old jasperserver.
[more on textAdjust and it's old incarnation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#textField_isStretchWithOverflow)

Comment: you are right. I am trying to open this textAdjust with 6.4.3 and it worked fine after i open with 6.12.2.